# vulkan warnings

Tags: vulkan

When I use the vulkaninfo command on Ubuntu 20.04, I get the following warnings:

```
WARNING: [Loader Message] Code 0 : terminator_CreateInstance: Failed to CreateInstance in ICD 2.  Skipping ICD.
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0

WARNING: lavapipe is not a conformant vulkan implementation, testing use only.
WARNING: lavapipe is not a conformant vulkan implementation, testing use only.
```

When I run vkcube, I get the following:

```
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0

Selected GPU 0: Intel(R) HD Graphics 530 (SKL GT2), type: 1
```

How can I resolve these warnings?